# How to draw a bar chart serie over another one bar chart serie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm using Jqplot and I want to draw two series on my graph.
I want these two series to be drawn as bar chart. I also want the first series to be drawn over the second one in case of there x value are the same.

How can I do it? I've tried to specify the `barPadding` option to `0` but the two series are drawn side by side.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "first series drawn over the second one".  Would a stacked bar chart suit your purposes?  Check the third example on this page: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.

What I mean is that I have two series to be drawn. Let say the two series are order on xaxis by date. I want the two series to be drawn at exactly the same place if they have the same x-value. But my first series is more important that the second one (lets say an alert series for the first one and a 'normal' one for the second); so when I have one value of each series to be drawn at the same place, I want the first one to be drawn in front of the second one (whatever the value of the first series is greater or not than the second one).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the bar chart plugin supports that.  Series are either drawn side-by-side or stacked.  You may need to create your own version of the plugin to do what you want.